# Injecting Java EE resources into dynamically loaded classes

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, wildfly, apache-tomee, tomee-7

Here's a class that is generated/loaded at runtime by a Java EE application (the `@Default Bar` bean is provided by the same application):

```
public class Foo {

    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;
    @Resource private UserTransaction tx;
    @EJB private MyEJB ejb;
    @Inject Bar bar;

    public Foo() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct () { ... }

    public void businessMethod() { ... }

}
```

Here's how it's instantiated:

```
    import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Unmanaged;
    ...

    @Inject private BeanManager bm;
    ...

    Class clazz = loadClazz();

    Unmanaged unmanaged = new Unmanaged(bm, clazz);

    Object obj = unmanaged.newInstance()
            .produce()
            .inject()
            .postConstruct()
            .get();
```

With JBoss/WildFly, all the fields are injected correctly, including EntityManager, EJB, UserTransaction etc.

With TomEE and GlassFish, Java EE resources are ignored, and only the `bar` field gets injected.

1. Should this be considered a bug in TomEE and GlassFish, or is it just a white spot in JavaEE/CDI spec that is implemented differently in application servers? It's definitely not a pure CDI issue because both GlassFish and WildFly use the same CDI implementation, namely [JBoss Weld](http://weld.cdi-spec.org);
2. How can I achieve the above with TomEE and GlassFish? Portable solution is preferred, but some server-dependent code is OK (I'm afraid it's inevitable with problems of that kind).

---

The overall objective is to provide the full range of CDI injections (simple `@Inject` as well as Java EE resources like `@PersistenceContext`, `@Resource`, `@EJB` etc.) to dynamic code. My first attempt was to generate a class on-the-fly that would incorporate annotated fields + dynamic business logic (and yes, it worked, though in WildFly only). Generally speaking, I have a set of dynamic injection definitions like this:

```
@Annotation(param = "value") @Qualifier1 @Qualifier2 ... Type name;
```

where `Annotation` is one of `Inject`, `PersistenceContext`, `Resource`, `EJB` etc., and I want to obtain an instance that would have been injected if this were inside a CDI managed bean. Thus, a hypothetic method would be acceptable that would take injection metadata and return the corresponding instance.

Comment: What version of TomEE are you using?

Comment: TomEE 7.0.0-M3 (latest devel snapshot with JavaEE 7 support)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [declaring resources via producer fields](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#declaring_resource)?

Doing so, you can `@Inject` your `EntityManager`, `UserTransaction` etc. without resorting to pre-CDI annotations.

Since CDI injection via `@Inject` seems to be working in all your environments, this might be a viable solution.

Comment: With this approach, parameters like `lookup` for `@Resource`, `unitName` for `@PersistenceContext` etc. will be fixed. I want them be dynamic, too. 
Or maybe you suppose I could generate producer class as well (serving as a bridge between pre-CDI annotations and `@Inject`)? I'm afraid CDI container will neither pick up a dynamically loaded producer class